# How do I change the view sorting for this field?

Tags: entities, views

I am using Drupal 7 and I have a List (text) field showing a list in this format:

```
0|a  
1|b  
2|c  
3|d  
10|e  
11|f
```

Now when I create a view and sort it ascending order, list is showing in this order: a,b,e,f,c,d. I need it to be shown as a,b,c,d,e,f.

I have a lot of data. I had to choose a list of integers.

Is there is any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: This is actually a field formatting issue, not views sorting issue. I edited the question, hopefully making it easier to understand and address the actual problem.

Comment: Here's one issue regarding this https://drupal.org/node/637876